# Prevent multiple users from editing the same list item at the same time

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-list

I have a list on SharePoint Online, where I need to make sure that only one person can edit a list item at a time. For example, if Person A edits a list item, it MUST be clear to everyone else working, that Person A is working on this list item and no one else should be able to edit this item.

As this is a list I am unable to turn the check in/check out feature on like I could if it was a document library.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

I have tried adding the below code to both the NewForm.aspx and Edit Form.aspx pages but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/%20sites/Devsite%20/SPServices.0.7.2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/Devsite/jqueryv1.8.3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">  
var loggedInUser="";  
 $(document).ready(function(){   

     document.getElementById('CheckedOutTo_8eb26269-8497-4b14-9785-ca206415c404_$TextField').disabled = true;  
     var checkInOutValue=$('[name="CheckInOut_9c53da6b-28f9-4200-9823-36913cf0e610_$RadioButtonChoiceField1"]:radio:checked').val();  
     var checkedOutToValue=document.getElementById('CheckedOutTo_8eb26269-8497-4b14-9785-ca206415c404_$TextField').value;  
     var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({  
         fieldNames: ["Name", "Title"],  
         debug: false  
     });  
     loggedInUser=thisUsersValues.Title;  
     if(checkInOutValue=="Check-Out")  
     {  
         if(loggedInUser!=checkedOutToValue)  
         {  
//if the user doesn’t belong to the CheckedOutTo field then don’t allow the //user to edit an item .instead redirect the user to allitems.aspx page  
             $('[name="CheckInOut_9c53da6b-28f9-4200-9823-36913cf0e610_$RadioButtonChoiceField"]').prop('disabled',true);  
             alert("This item is checked out to: "+checkedOutToValue+". You will not be able to edit this item.");  
             window.location.href="/DealingFXTradeSlip/Lists/FXTradeSlip/Dealers.aspx";  
         }  
     }  
     radioButtonChange();  

 });   

 function radioButtonChange()  
 {  

     $('#CheckInOut_9c53da6b-28f9-4200-9823-36913cf0e610_ChoiceRadioTable').change(  
         function(){               
             var checkInOutValue=$('[name="CheckInOut_9c53da6b-28f9-4200-9823-36913cf0e610_$RadioButtonChoiceField"]:radio:checked').val();  
     if(checkInOutValue=="Check-Out")  
     {  
         document.getElementById('CheckedOutTo_8eb26269-8497-4b14-9785-ca206415c404_$TextField').value=loggedInUser;  
     }  
     else if(checkInOutValue=="Check-In")  
     {  
        document.getElementById('CheckedOutTo_8eb26269-8497-4b14-9785-ca206415c404_$TextField').value="";       
     }  
}); 
</script>​​
```

Comment: Please refer this link, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/check-in-and-check-out-functionality-for-custom-list-items-i/

Comment: Thanks Karthik. I have followed these instructions and changed the field ID's to match mine but unfortunately it isn't working. I have updated my main post with the code I have added to both the New and Edit form pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB method to block editing a list item when another user already edits. You need to do Custom code or JQuery/JSLink.

Comment: Thanks Lisa, I have updated my post with some code that I have added to both the New and Edit form pages (as per this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/check-in-and-check-out-functionality-for-custom-list-items-i/) but unfortunately isn't working.